# Add a profile box on top of ListView

Tags: android

I am following Udacity course on how to build a ListView + ArrayAdapter.
Now I want to implement my own little app, and that on top of the list there should be a user profile windows.
This is the original design and code:

The activity inflates the listview:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word_list);
```

And this is the `word_list` layout:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

But this is how I want it to look like:

[image]

I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Try using this [function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView#addHeaderView(android.view.View))

You need create `header.xml` and add it to `ListView`. For example:

```
listView.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null));
```

Comment: And that header.xml will be a simple LinearLayout with an imageview and textview inside? Or it should also be a ListView itself

Comment: Also, it has to be done this way ? i.e programatically? Or I can somehow make it part of the xml before inflating?

Comment: You need create to `header.xml` file